# I am using `org.apache.poi` api with atlassian jira but it's giving error

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, jira

I use below code in normal application, it is working fine. But when I use the same code in jira(simple Jira plugin) it shows this error :

> org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : null

I am new to jira. Kindly suggest how can i use.

```
 XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
        XSSFCell cell = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        XSSFSheet page_level_sheet;
        XSSFRow sheet1_header = null;
        try {

            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            page_level_sheet = workbook.createSheet("Summary");
            sheet1_header = page_level_sheet.createRow(0);
        sheet1_header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Application Name");;

            sheet1_header.createCell(1).setCellValue("Total Urls");;

             sheet1_header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Urls With Tags");;
            sheet1_header.createCell(3).setCellValue("Coverage %");;


            for (int i=1;i<100;i++)
            {
                sheet1_header = page_level_sheet.createRow(i);
                sheet1_header.createCell(0).setCellValue("51115");
                sheet1_header.createCell(1).setCellValue("5111d5");
                sheet1_header.createCell(2).setCellValue("511f15");
                sheet1_header.createCell(3).setCellValue("511v15");

            }

            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/poi-generated-file.xlsx"));
            workbook.write(fos);
            fos.close();
   }catch(Exception e)
   {
       log.info("erorr is "+e);
   }
```

Comment: in your JIRA environment, there is no location like `D:/`, try to specify a relative path to save that file

Comment: I take temp location . i tried taking jira location also .

Comment: When you change that path, does it give the same errors?

Comment: after change path same error giving

Comment: The `log.info("error is "+e)` uses `e.toString()` which only returns a short description of this throwable. While developing you need the full stacktrace. So do using `e.printStackTrace()` to print the full stacktrace to `System..err` or do using [printStackTrace(PrintWriter s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace-java.io.PrintWriter-) if that is not possible. Then please show the full stacktrace.

Comment: when i use e.fillInStackTrace() same error is raising -- org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : null

Comment: As said we need the full stacktrace as printed using `Throwable.printStackTrace` to be able to help.